# Probability for expression that evaluates to 0 - sum with binominals

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Let $s, l, p_1, p_2, \dotsc \in (0,1)$ be real numbers, where $\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i \leq 1$ and $l+s<1$
$x_1, x_2, \dotsc$ are undefined variables.
Imagine a machine that produces arithmetic expressions like
$$ x_{i_1} \circ_1 \dotsb \circ_{k} x_{i_{k+1}} $$
where $k, i_1 , \dotsc, i_k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\circ_1, \dotsc, \circ_k \in \{+, -\}$. Machine produces an expression $x_{i_1} \circ_1 \dotsb \circ_{k} x_{i_{k+1}}$ with a probability
$$
P(x_{i_1} \circ_1 \dotsb \circ_{k-1} x_{i_k}) = \binom{k}{q}s^ql^{k-q}p_{i_1}\dotsm p_{i_{k+1}}
$$
where $q$ equals to the number of $+$signs in $x_{i_1} \circ_1 \dotsb \circ_{k} x_{i_{k+1}}$ (t.i. $q = |\{i \in \{1, \dotsc, k\}\mid \circ_i = +\}|$).

**Example:**
Machine produces an expression $x_1 + x_2$ with probability $sp_1p_2$ and expression $x_1 - x_1$ with probability $lp_1^2$. Expression $x_1x_2$ or expression $-x_2$ cannot be produced.

Notice how  expressions $x_1-x_1$ and  $x_1 + x_2 - x_1 - x_2$ and $x_1 - x_2 + x_2 - x_1$ evaluate to $0$ for all possible $x_1, x_2  \in \mathbb R$. **What is the probability $P([0])$ of producing an expression that evaluates to $0$ for all possible $x_{i_j} \in \mathbb R$ ?**

$P([0])$ is a sum over the probs for all the expressions that evalute to 0. Expressions as such consists of finite number of different $x_i$. For every $+x_i$ in the expression, there must also be one $-x_i$ in the expression. I tried to sum the probabilities based on the highest index $n$ of a $x_n$ in the expression. Every selection $k_1, \dotsc, k_n \in \mathbb{N_0} $, where  $k_n \neq 0$ describes a set of expressions that evaluates to 0, where $-x_i$ occurs exactly $k_i$ times and $x_n$ has the highest index of all $x_i$ that occur in the expression. With some combinatorics, we got a sum
$$
P([0]) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{\substack{k_1, \dotsc, k_n \in \mathbb{N_0} \\ k_n \neq 0}} 
\frac{1}{2}\binom{2K}{k_1, k_1, \dotsb, k_n, k_n}\binom{2K}{K-1} s^{K-1}l^{K}\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{2k_i}
$$
where $K = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i$

I am stuck at evaluating the sum. I will be also satisfied by an answer that doesn't use the upper sum.
*I noticed that the sum $ \sum_{m=1}^\infty (q_1  + q_2 + q_3 + \dotsb ) ^ m$ has a similar structure.*

*You can also take as granted that P([0]) exists and is less or equal to 1.*

EDIT:

Expression evaluates to $0$ if and only if each group ff $x_i$ sums to $0$

EDIT2:
A machine can also not generate an expresion with some probability. If $p_i$ sums to less than 1, prob. for generating nothing is nonzero.

Comment: I wouldnt be surprised if there are some minor calculation errors in my sum, but the main structure is  right.

Comment: Why is the sum of $p_i$ is not exactly $1$? Are they discrete or (partly) continuous?

Comment: Do you assume that the sum of $\pm x_i$, which includes at least two different $x_i$ cannot be $0$ unless each group of $x_i$ sums to $0$?

Comment: @user yes, each group of $x_i$ must sum to 0

Comment: @user we can complicate the machine way more and generate polynominals from $\mathbb{R}[x_1, ..., x_n]$. The sum of $p_i$ originates from that machine.

Comment: You need to mention this in your question, otherwise the problem can hardly be solvable (if ratio of some numbers is rational).

Comment: It is a very strange situation if $p_i$ do not some to $1$. What happens in the rest trials? Does $l+s=1$?

Comment: @user there is no guarantee that a machine will succesfully generate an expression. There can also exist (nonzero) probability of not generating an expression... Will that be ok?

Comment: Then one can include the event "no expression is generated" with probability $p_0=1-\sum_{i\ge1}p_i$. You did not answer the question about $l+s$.

Comment: Take for granted $l+s < 1$

Comment: This is not understandable. What happens in the rest cases?

Comment: All the rest cases can be includet ino "no expr4ession is generated"

Comment: If it is included in this way it cannot influence $s+l$.

Comment: @user vhy should then $l+s=1$?

Comment: Machine choose a number. If it successful, it choose the sign. Or can the choice of the sign also fail?

Comment: No, there are 2 possible scenarios: 1. machine chooses an expresion , 2. it generates nothing

Comment: @user but that shouldn't be important for the sum..?

Comment: If the sign is an obligatory part of an expression  $l+s=1$ should hold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134017/discussion-between-urh-and-user).